# Changing output fonts in ipython

Tags: python, css, fonts, ipython

My ipython fonts have been corrupted following the latest windows update.

While waiting for it to be fixed, I am trying to fix my Ipython Notebook.

As you can see from below, the output fonts are corrupted which is very distracting.

[image]

I have managed to fix the input fonts by adding this to my custom.css file:

```
div.input_area {
font-family: 'Consolas';
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    background: rbga(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

But if I try to do the same for the output_area, nothing happens.

```
div.output_area {
    font-family: 'Consolas';
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    background: rbga(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

What do I need to do to fix the corruption of my output area fonts?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
div.output_area pre {
    font-family: Consolas, monospace;
font-size: small;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code you gave, how it helps answer the question?

Comment: It just needs to be copied into my custom.css file